# "Ihr seid anders" - different from each other or from the others?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

If I am talking with two german friends of mine, and I say "Ihr seid anders", am I implying they are different from each other or that they are different (from other germans, for example)? Is there a different way to express each one of the ideas or it depends on the context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you tell Germans

> Ihr seid anders

It means they are different from everyone else.

If you tell them

> Ihr seid verschieden

It means they are different from each other

Comment: I believe that this is a case like _das gleiche_ vs. _dasselbe_, where there's a "normative meaning difference", which is not respected very much in everyday language.  I for one would accept both interpretations for "anders", and would use "verschieden" only in a more formal register. (But there might be regional differences as well!)

Comment: Lies Mal die Definitionen und Beispiele zu anders und verschieden vom Duden durch. Du kannst die Worte nicht einfach beliebig austauschen.  Oder würdest du sagen "er lebt in einer verschiedenen Welt"?

Comment: Was der Duden sagt, ist mir beim Reden ziemlich egal. _Er lebt in einer verschiedenen Welt_ würde ich nicht sagen; ich habe auch nicht gemeint, dass die Wörter austauschbar sind, sondern dass in der Praxis _anders_ sehr wohl in der Bedeutung von _verschieden_ verwendet wird (verschieden hat, sicher aufgrund des Registerunterschiedes, eine markiertere, spezifische Bedeutung).

Comment: Das mag sein, in dem vom  OP angefragten Satz finde ich die Verwendung allerdings super eindeutig.